# convert sql compact database to MySQL sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-ce

I was looking for a smaill windows program to convert a small sql compact database (.sdf) to (.sql) for mySql. Please recommend one. Already tried ExportSqlCe40.exe. Thank You.

Comment: A lot of people use http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/ so I'm wondering what error's you're getting. Maybe you can post some more details.

Comment: @hafichuk: well, it exports the sdf file a sqlite-compatible way. My cloud hosting provider supports mysql and postgre. So thereby I get syntax errors. Thanks again

Comment: I would be happy to consider supporting MySQL syntax with exportsqlce, but I would need to know what syntax errors you get...

Comment: @ErikEJ: Well, I did it using this freeware - Bullzip MS Access to MySQL - but just so you know it said that there was a syntax error around the CREATE TABLE line. In fact, even I thought it was weird. But I would blame it on Auto_Increment. It wouldn't do anything at first. And this program I used, it gave off an error. So, I changed an option in it from CSV to MyISAM. But, it gave off syntax error when trying to create table. So, I created the table format manually and deleted out CREATE TABLE and the comments from the .sql file.Still, I got those messages. So, basically, both (continued)

Comment: the syntax are completely different. Nothing is similar. but the bullzip thingy works, see if you can decompile it. And thanks for your interest, by the way. And I appreciate your work, used it in the past. Thanks again. Oh, and here are the sql files that I reseived as output From bullzip  - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90727979/sql%20files/Bullzip.sql                From ExportSQLCE40 - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90727979/sql%20files/ExportSQLCe40.sql

Comment: the syntax are completely different. Nothing is similar. but the bullzip thingy works, see if you can decompile it. And thanks for your interest, by the way. And I appreciate your work, used it in the past. Thanks again. Oh, and here are the sql files that I reseived as output From bullzip  - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90727979/sql%20files/Bullzip.sql                From ExportSQLCE40 - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90727979/sql%20files/ExportSQLCe40.sql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it! Downloaded [this](http://primeworks-mobile.com/Downloads/Files/DPW/DPW_2.3.633.html) to convert sdf to accdb and then [this](http://www.bullzip.com/download/a2m/msa2mys_5_1_0_232.zip) to export the accdb to my MySQL Server.